# Android send data from service with sendOrderedBroadcast

Tags: android

i'm trying to send data with `sendOrderedBroadcast` to BroadcastListener such as :

```
public class ServiceReceiveSubjects extends IntentService {
    public static String RECEIVE_SERVER_DATA = "ServiceReceiveNewSubject";

    public ServiceReceiveSubjects() {
        super("ServiceReceiveSubject");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        receive();
    }

    private void receive() {
        String jsonStr = "DATA";
        NotifyMsg( jsonStr );
    }
    private void NotifyMsg( String data) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(M.ACTION_BROADCAST_RECEIVE_SUBJECT_REFRESH);
        intent.putExtra(RECEIVE_SERVER_DATA, data);
        sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
    }
}
```

now i want to get this putExtra data with boardcast in activity:

```
final BroadcastReceiver NotifyReceivePostsRefresh = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent i) {
        if (G.currentActivity.getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            Bundle extras = G.currentActivity.getIntent().getExtras ();
            Log.e("JSON: ",extras);
        }
    }
};
```

unfortunately i get `null` for `extras` variable

Comment: Hi, below answer help or not if solving issue?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK oh i'm sorry sir. i'm forget to accept your answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Intent which receiving  as parameter in `onReceive` for getting values sended by `sendOrderedBroadcast`:

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent i) {
        if (i.getExtras() != null) {
            Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
        }
    }
```

> unfortunately i get null for extras variable

You are sending key-value in Intent instead of `Bundle` so just use `i.getStringExtra` for getting value :

```
 if (i!= null) {
     String strData = i.getStringExtra(ServiceReceiveSubjects.RECEIVE_SERVER_DATA);
     Log.e("JSON: ",strData);
   }
```